# Select record from table1 where value from table2

Tags: sql-server, join

I have 2 tables here:

```
table1
id    name    idfrom  idto
 1    test         2     3
 2    test3        1     9

table2
id   branch  status
 2   a       from
 1   b       from
 9   c       to
 3   d       to
```

How do I select branch from table2 and table1 based on status in table2?

I want the result to look like this:

```
id   name     branchfrom   branchto 
 1   test     a            d
 2   test3    b            c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer it doesn't mean I like it.

```
            SELECT id, name, bfrom.branch branchfrom, bto.branch branchto
              FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, branch
              FROM table2
             WHERE status = 'from') bfrom
                ON t1.idfrom = bfrom.id 
INNER JOIN (SELECT id, branch
              FROM table2
             WHERE status = 'to') bto
                ON t1.idto = bto.id;
```

I use INNER JOIN as sample only. You must adjust with your requirement (which you didn't clearly specify).

Comment: @EKo Does this query return any values? Also, why use a subquery when you can do a direct join on the columns?

Comment: thanks for the heads-up, @Nepali Rookie, i fixed the joins. i wrote the answer from mobile browser.

Comment: Sure, quite honestly I wouldn't recommend using `hardcoded` values in the `WHERE` clause when you have a `key` available. Having said that, a subquery is quite unnecessary in this case.

Comment: if table2 not consists column `status`, i wouldn't use it in the query. we never knew what kind of `key` the OP use for table2.

Comment: Actually, we do know what the key is in this case. If you look in your query, you are using exactly the `key` I am talking about. The `id` column in table 2 joins back to both `idfrom` and `idto` columns in table1. :)

Comment: what if table2 use both column `id` and `status` as `pk`? i think you then need to add 1 `and` in each of your joins' condition. anyway, have you actually tried both queries performance on large data? othetwise, i think it's only matter of personal pteference.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79153/discussion-between-nepali-rookie-and-tjeloep).

Comment: man.., this is midnight here. sorry, i'm going to sleep. have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following should do (assuming you're wanting to join on id in both tables):

```
select t1.id, t1.name, f.branch as branchfrom, t.branch as branchto
from table1 as t1
join table2 as f
  on f.id = t1.id
  and f.status = 'from'
join table2 as t
  on t.id = t1.id
  and t.status = 'to'
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
select t1.id, t1.name, f.branch as branchfrom, f1.branch as branchto
from table1 as t1
join table2 as f
  on t1.idfrom = f.id
join table2 as f1
  on t1.idto = f1.id
```

Please see here for demo: [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/baa85/3/0)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is better or worse than what the other two people have suggested but

```
select 
  t1.name,
  (select
    t2.branch
  from
    table2 t2
  where 
     t1.idfrom = t2.id
  ) as branchfrom,
  (select
     t2.branch
   from
     table2 t2
   where 
     t1.idto = t2.id
  ) as branchto
from 
  table1 t1
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4796e0/5/0)

Answer (score 0):

Use this Code:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 (
  id int,
  name varchar(10),
  idfrom int,
  idto int

)

CREATE TABLE #table2 (
  id int,
  branch char,
  statuss varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #table1
  VALUES (1, 'test', 2, 3)
INSERT INTO #table1
  VALUES (2, 'test3', 1, 9)

INSERT INTO #table2
  VALUES (2, 'a', 'From')
INSERT INTO #table2
  VALUES (1, 'b', 'From')
INSERT INTO #table2
  VALUES (9, 'c', 'to')
INSERT INTO #table2
  VALUES (3, 'd', 'to')




SELECT
  a.id,
  a.name,
  (SELECT
    b.branch
  FROM #table2 b
  WHERE a.idfrom = b.id
  AND b.statuss = 'FROM')
  AS BranchFrom,
  (SELECT
    b.branch
  FROM #table2 b
  WHERE a.idto = b.id
  AND b.statuss = 'to')
  AS BranchTo
FROM #table1 a
```